# Select one result in sql row?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Here is my problem I would like to solve.

Step 1: Select which messages with the column "at_idsujet" equal to "3" for example.
Step 2: Among all results, I would run a second query that will select the result with the column "id" equal to "7" for example.

All this would serve me recover the position of the message in a specific order. For example, it could be the third post of a topic. I would therefore have the number 3.

Here's the code I get for now, a little complicated ..

```
                $bdd->query('SET @compteur=0');
                $gotonbpage = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id, @compteur:=@compteur+1 AS num_ligne FROM (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = ?) WHERE at_idsujet = ?');
                $gotonbpage->execute(array($get_gotomsg,$ft_infosgotomsg['at_idsujet']));
                    $fetch_fgotopage = $gotonbpage->fetch('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = '.$ft_infosgotomsg['id'].'');
```

The variable "$gotonbpage" is the subject ID.
The variable "$ft_infosgotomsg['at_idsujet']" is the topic that has the message that I research.

Warning, sql code is PDO.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Aymeric.

Answer (score 0):

Add LIMIT in your SELECT query

```
$bdd->query('SET @compteur=0');
$gotonbpage = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id, @compteur:=@compteur+1 AS num_ligne FROM (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = ?) WHERE at_idsujet = ?');
$gotonbpage->execute(array($get_gotomsg,$ft_infosgotomsg['at_idsujet']));
$fetch_fgotopage = bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = '.$ft_infosgotomsg['id'].' LIMIT 1');
$fetch_fgotopage->execute();
$singlePage = $fetch_fgotopage->fetch();
```

Comment: There is only one result due out when selecting the ID.
An ID can not exist twice in this table.

In addition, the query "$gotonbpage" is incorrect because I get an ugly error.

Comment: Your second query in not working right let me update

Comment: I get this error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias' in C:\xampp\htdocs\topics.php:419 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\topics.php(419): PDO->prepare('SELECT id, @com...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\topics.php on line 419

Comment: Would have the second request is made with respect to the first. The second is to select a specific line among all the results. This line will be selected by the ID column with a specific value.

Comment: Why you have use `FROM (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = ?)` ?

Comment: You have not added table name in first query

Comment: This is the table "messages" in which I would like to search.

Comment: You can write like this way `SELECT id, @compteur:=@compteur+1 AS num_ligne FROM messages  WHERE id = ? AND at_idsujet = ?`

Comment: The query works, and I had already tested in this way before I get what I want.
He finds one result, the one I want but its position among the other messages will necessarily be the number "1" and not its position in the list.
If I take the third message, the request will indicate that it is the first.

I want a query that selects all messages in a category and that among the results, I can select a line, always in PHP.